# How to make multiple databases in mLab MongoDB add-on in Heroku

Tags: heroku, mlab

I am using mLab MongoDB add-on free version in Heroku.

I want to make two sets of data bases(development, production). But it does not allow me to make multiple databases. Any possible solution to fix this problem?
The paid solutions seem to only increase store capacity and other few features related to monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sent an email to mLab. The response is that it is not possible to make multiple databases with a single mLab add-on in heroku. Instead what I can do is add a completely new mLab add-on. But this would be cost inefficient and data cannot be transferred directly from one database to another.

The other solution they suggested, is simply to make mLab database using mLab account itself instead of heroku. Then I would be able to make multiple database in a single instance with a better pricing.